# Explain dynamically bound and static methods

Tags: java

I"m a little confused on how private methods can be static and but public must be dynamically bound.

Comment: Your question is not clear (at-least for me), can you add more details?

Comment: The modifiers `private`, `public` and `protected` imply visibility. They have to do nothing with binding. What do you mean by your question?

Comment: I agree with thinksteep. When posting questions like this it is best practice to include at least one example code snippet of each case (here you would have 3 snippets, what you are trying to do and doesn't work, the static case, and dynamic case). The more examples and details you provide, the better quality answer you will receive.

Comment: this is for a class I'm taking and that is basically the question there is not code snippet

Answer (score 9):

Dynamic binding means that the decision as to which code is run is made at runtime. This is the basis of polymorphism.

Public, package access and protected methods are dynamically bound. Subclasses can override the methods and provide alternative implementations. Private methods cannot be overridden, so dynamic binding is not needed for them.

Static methods are not dynamically bound (the clue's in the name) as they are defined on the class itself rather than being unique to each object.

Comment: +1 This is correct answer. Dynamism is bounded at runtime and static methods HIDE the implementation.

Answer (score 6):

**Dynamic Binding or Late Binding**

*Dynamic Binding* refers to the case where compiler is not able to resolve the call and the binding is done at runtime only. Let's try to understand this. Suppose we have a class named `SuperClass` and another class named `SubClass` extends it. Now a `SuperClass` reference can be assigned to an object of the type `SubClass` as well. If we have a method (say `someMethod()`) in the `SuperClass` which we override in the `SubClass` then a call of that method on a `SuperClass` reference can only be resolved at runtime as the compiler can't be sure of what type of object this reference would be pointing to at runtime.

```
...
SuperClass superClass1 = new SuperClass();
SuperClass superClass2 = new SubClass();
...

superClass1.someMethod(); // SuperClass version is called
superClass2.someMethod(); // SubClass version is called
....
```

Here, we see that even though both the object references `superClass1` and `superClass2` are of type `SuperClass` only, but at run time they refer to the objects of types SuperClass and `SubClass` respectively.

Hence, at compile time the compiler can't be sure if the call to the method `someMethod()` on these references actually refer to which version of the method - the super class version or the sub class version.

Thus, we see that dynamic binding in Java simply binds the method calls (inherited methods only as they can be overriden in a sub class and hence compiler may not be sure of which version of the method to call) based on the actual object type and not on the declared type of the object reference.

---

**Static Binding or Early Binding**

If the compiler can resolve the binding at the compile time only then such a binding is called Static Binding or Early Binding. All the instance method calls are always resolved at runtime, but all the static method calls are resolved at compile time itself and hence we have static binding for static method calls. Because static methods are class methods and hence they can be accessed using the class name itself (in fact they are encourgaed to be used using their corresponding class names only and not by using the object references) and therefore access to them is required to be resolved during compile time only using the compile time type information. That's the reason why static methods can not actually be overriden. Read more - [Can you override static methods in Java?](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/can-you-override-static-methods-in-java.html)

*Access to all the member variables in Java follows static binding as Java doesn't support (in fact, it discourages) polymorphic behavior of member variables.*

[Apart from this discussion, you can not override *static* (as mentioned by the above link), *private* and *final* methods in Java.]

Answer (score 0):

static methods are class level methods so u can accessed through the class name only but methods must be public

Comment: Static methods don't have to be public, but if they're private, they can only be accessed by other static methods of the same class...

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In **Class polymorphism**, the **Object Reference Variable of the Subclass is passed as an Argument
to the method which accepts the Parameter which is an Object Reference Variable of type
Superclass**.`Public and Protected and Default members can be dynamically bounded`, **Private members are not
are not inherited**.

**2. Static members are for the class, and its not bounded** to any individual object, so its not
dynamically bounded.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the `this` reference inside a `private` method, you can just as well make it `static` and it won't make any difference. A `private` method will never need to be dynamically bound in either case so at the implementation level it is really irrelevant which you choose. It helps readabilty, though, when you mark the method `static` since then it is clear the method does not depend on the state of the object.